# wrong errors required fields in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Since some day I get this errors when I want to edit and save a product in the admin:

1. This link_rewrite field is required at least in English (English)
2. Products must be in at least one category.
3. This product must be in the default category.

But all this field are filled well.

The first error (link_rewrite) I fixed (workaround) by editting \classes\Product.php line 308 changed 'required' => true to 'required' => false. But for error 2 and 3 I didn't find a workaround yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your version ? Do you use Overrides somewhere ?

Comment: version 1.6.0.9, no overrides. It looks like this errors appeared after a browser update. In Chrome it there was already an error since a longer time, but now in Firefox as well.

Comment: Update: when I uncheck the categories and then check again I don't get the errors and works well. So looks like when I open the product the system (javascript?) doesn't recognize the already checked categories.

Comment: If you have no hooks, I would recommend you to update to last 1.6 version

Answer (score 0):

How I can remember this version wasn't stable and such issues can appear. If you don't want to update your version to the latest version of core you can look through newer versions of the core, these issues could be fixed in later releases. Also, your solution about first error doesn't seem reliable. You didn't fix a problem, you just have hidden it and this can lead to more dangerous outcomes(especially with a friendly URL)

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thanks for reply. Yes my solution for the first is just a temporary workaround. I'm gonna try to update within the same core.